# Filter AppCmd to running sites

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, appcmd

I have a script that uses `appcmd` to find sites using a particular `vdir` and iterates through them to find which ones are currently running

```
appcmd.exe list vdir /physicalPath:Z:\My\Path
:: save sites to array

:: foreach SiteName in array
appcmd.exe list site SiteName
:: hunt for "Started" in the output
```

but I would like to directly filter down to *running* sites using said virtual directory. I have expectations that there's a `/parameter:value` that does exactly that, but I can't seem to find a list of possible parameters.

- Best would be arguments on the `list vdir` call that render the `list site` unnecessary.
- Second best would be a filter on the `list site` call that removes the need to hunt for "Started"
- If there is a (complete) list of `appcmd` parameters on MSDN, TechNet, or somewhere that proves this is not possible, that would also be helpful.

Comment: You should use `PowerShell` instead

Comment: Company policy restricts the languages we can use. :) The non-`appcmd` processing is actually Python. I'll take the `PS` recommendation under advisement, though.

Comment: PS ties directly into IIS with IIS-Module and would be silly to be ruled out IMHO as its MS->MS technology and in fact the Server Manager / IIS Manager just execute PowerShell cmdlets in the background :) PS has replaced appcmd.

Comment: @dirt - It is a misconception that IIS Manager uses PowerShell cmdlets under the hood. It uses the Web Administration API which is mostly COM. Appcmd, PowerShell and the GUI just use the API. You can still use the GUI without the PowerShell Provider for IIS installed. But I agree you should use the PowerShell provider over appcmd. Much more powerful.